# How to calculate thermodynamic parameters from quadratic form of the Van't Hoff Equation?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have drug binding data giving me Ka values for a set of associated temperatures. This allows me to plot ln(Ka) vs. 1/T, which I can fit to a second degree polynomial i.e. y = ax^2 + bx + c. From this, I would like to calculate thermodynamic parameters deltaS and deltaH.

To do this, my understanding is I would have to use a nonlinear form of the Van't Hoff equation, e.g. equation 3 from this paper:

https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8247/13/6/134/htm

Now, I have my values for a, b, and c. But I am having trouble figuring out how to use this information to get deltaS and deltaH values. In the supporting information for the above paper (https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8247/13/6/134/s1), they appear to do this, but when I plug in their values for a, b, and c, I do not get their reported values for dH and dS.

Sorry for the formatting and if what I am asking is unclear.

Comment: The quadratic fit does not come directly from eq 3. Rather it results from a Taylor expansion whose derivation is described here: https://analyticalsciencejournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jssc.201100029

Comment: Described even more clearly here: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acsomega.9b02689